# git for (MATLAB) lib in use -- developing at the same time

Tags: git, workflow

I am very new to git and trying to get into it. I want to use it for training purposes for a private MATLAB library. I am not quite sure yet how to deal with it if I want the last "final" version of my git repository to be available for other MATLAB sessions, so I don't want to have my MATLAB sessions switch to the development branch whenever I switch to that branch to alter some code.

Am I right that for this use case I would do and would need to do the following?

Have a local git repository which is the working directory, for debugging purposes I can direct MATLAB's path to that directory, so that MATLAB will use the current HEAD version of the files which I am coding at the moment.

For the live use, I would create another git folder from which I pull the last final version of my library. So that MATLAB sessions using this path are not being winded up when I change the branch to develop or bugfix in my "development folder".

---

This seems to serve as an answer. Is this the way to go?
http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/10/git-checkout-multiple-branches-at-same.html

Answer (score 0):

Your approach make sense if you need to both use and develop at the same time, if MATLAB allows to work with two different pahts it's a good solution.

On the other side, the branches are very powerful for such kind of behaviour and it's very simple to `git checkout <branch>` in order to switch from one environment to the other without having to change anything in MATLAB. You just need to commit your modifications in your respective branches.

By having 2 repos each checked out to a different branch, you're missing the best advantage of working with git in my opinion.

Hope that it will help you.